# Why is phoenix_ecto failing to compile on the :model in the changeset?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir-mix

When I try to run `mix deps.get` or `mix deps.compile` I get this error:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/phoenix_ecto/html.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/phoenix_ecto/html.ex:3: unknown key :model for struct Ecto.Changeset
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## How to fix this:

You need to upgrade your dependencies like so:

```
{:ecto, "~> 2.0.4"},
{:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0.1"},
{:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6.2"},
```

Then run `mix clean --all` and then `mix deps.get`.

## Why this is happening:

This error comes from your `phoenix_ecto` dependency being behind your `ecto` dependency. In [ecto v2.0.0](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/releases), `changeset.model` became `changeset.data`.

The code for `phoenix_ecto` is still using `model` on line three:

```
def to_form(%Ecto.Changeset{model: model, params: params} = changeset, opts) do
```

In [this commit](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_ecto/commit/96d5f0f7cc7aef6efecd1ff25f7c140e80842a3d), `phoenix_ecto` was upgraded to support the new version of `ecto`.

Comment: I was stuck on this for hours. Thanks FlaqueDeau!